# Multi slider function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function slider that fades the next section in and out, but not happy how I created the functions as I need to change the function each time I create a new section.

There a way to change this setup where only one function is needed so I can have 100 sections and just one function? Not 100 functions for each section to add/remove classes?

```js
$('#toSlide-2').on('click', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#slide-1').removeClass('in-view').addClass('out-of-view');
       $('#slide-2').addClass('in-view');
 })
 $('#toSlide-3').on('click', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#slide-2').removeClass('in-view').addClass('out-of-view');
       $('#slide-3').addClass('in-view');
 })
 $('#toSlide-4').on('click', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#slide-3').removeClass('in-view').addClass('out-of-view');
       $('#slide-4').addClass('in-view');
 })
```

```css
.out-of-view{
  opacity:0;
  }
.in-view{
  opacity:1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="slide-1" class="in-view">
  <h2>form 1</h2>
  <button id="toSlide-2">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-2" class="out-of-view">
  <h2>form 2</h2>
    <button id="toSlide-3">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-3" class="out-of-view">
  <h2>form 3</h2>
    <button id="toSlide-4">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-4" class="out-of-view">
  <h2>form 4 - done</h2>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of a working solution using jQuery.

```js
$('.buttons').on('click', function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().removeClass('in-view').addClass('out-of-view');
       $(this).parent().next().addClass('in-view');
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="slide-1" class="in-view">
  <h2>form 1</h2>
  <button class="buttons">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-2" class="out-of-view">
  <h2>form 2</h2>
    <button class="buttons">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-3" class="out-of-view">
  <h2>form 3</h2>
    <button class="buttons">button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the data attribute to determine which element id would be showed next like so:

```js
function init() {
  $('.in-view').show();
  $('.out-of-view').hide();
}

function slide(slideId1, slideId2) {
  $(`#${slideId1}`).hide();
  $(`#${slideId2}`).show();
}

$('.slide-btn').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  slide($(this).parent().attr("id"), $(this).data("next"));
});

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="slide-1" class="in-view">
  <h2>form 1</h2>
  <button class="slide-btn" data-next="slide-2">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-2" class="out-of-view">
  <h2>form 2</h2>
    <button class="slide-btn" data-next="slide-3">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-3" class="out-of-view">
  <h2>form 3</h2>
    <button class="slide-btn" data-next="slide-4">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-4" class="out-of-view">
  <h2>form 4 - done</h2>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JS function that will dynamically take the elements using a class selector and iterate over them and use the key word `this` in an event listener to select the next element sibling and add/remove class names.

Note: I added a class named `forms` and use that to get the element list of forms to use in the forEach loop.

Also, I suggest using `display: none/block` instead of `opacity`. This will keep the elements from pushing down the page with each iteration of selecting a button.

```js
// get your element list
const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".forms");

// iterate over the element list using forEach()
forms.forEach(function(v){
  // foreach value in the list, set a click event listener
  v.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // now use the key word 'this' to add/remove class names
    // then target the next sibling in the list to add/remove class names
    this.classList.remove("in-view");
    this.classList.add("out-of-view");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('out-of-view');
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('in-view');
  })
})
```

```css
.out-of-view{
  display:none;
  }
.in-view{
  display:block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="slide-1" class="in-view forms">
  <h2>form 1</h2>
  <button id="toSlide-2">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-2" class="out-of-view forms">
  <h2>form 2</h2>
    <button id="toSlide-3">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-3" class="out-of-view forms">
  <h2>form 3</h2>
    <button id="toSlide-4">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-4" class="out-of-view forms">
  <h2>form 4 - done</h2>
</form>
```

JQuery Version:

No matter how many form elements in your HTML, as long as they have the class `forms`, they will be iterated over and processed in the function.

Also, use less lines of code and change the css directly in your JQuery using `.css()`

```js
// get your element list
const $forms = $(".forms");

// iterate over the element list using.each()
$forms.each(function() {
  // use $(this) to define the element being clicked on
  $(this).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
    $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
  })
})
```

```css
.out-of-view {
  display: none;
}

.in-view {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="slide-1" class="in-view forms">
  <h2>form 1</h2>
  <button id="toSlide-2">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-2" class="out-of-view forms">
  <h2>form 2</h2>
  <button id="toSlide-3">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-3" class="out-of-view forms">
  <h2>form 3</h2>
  <button id="toSlide-4">button</button>
</form>

<form id="slide-4" class="out-of-view forms">
  <h2>form 4 - done</h2>
</form>
```